# Registration form is not submiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here it is my code form is not subbmiting.registration is not completed.please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {        

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 12,                      
            remote:"users.php"

        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 12
        },          
        email:
        {
            required: true,
            minlength: 15,
            maxlength: 50,
            remote:"email.php"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            minlength: "username is 6 to 12 characters",
            maxlength:  "username is 6 to 12 characters",   
            required: " username should be required",
            remote: " username should be already exists"
        },
        password: {
            minlength: "password is 6 to 15 characters",
            maxlength:  "password is 6 to 12 characters 12",        
            required: " password should be required",       
        },
        email: {
            minlength: "Email is  15 to 50 characters",
            maxlength:  "Email is  15 to 50 characters",    
            required: " Email should be required",
            remote: " Email should be already exists"           
        }
    },
             // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo       
    submitHandler: function() 
    {
        alert("submitted!---------");
        $("#signupform").submit();
    }, 
    // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
            {      
        error.prependTo( element.parent().next() );
    },

    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        // set &nbsp; as text for IE
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    }
});


// propose username by combining first- and lastname
$("#username").focus(function() {
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    if(firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
        this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
    }
}); 
});
```

and this is my form

```
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" method="post" action="register.php" style="padding-top:70px;" >             
        <table align="center" style="height:200px;">            
               <tr>             
                <td class="field"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Username:</span>&nbsp;<input id="username" name="username" style="height:25px;width:155px;" onKeyPress='return alphanumericPass(event, false)' type="text" value="Username (6 to 12 chars)" maxlength="12" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username (6 to 12 chars)')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username (6 to 12 chars)'" placeholder="Username"  /></td>
                <td class=""></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>                      
                <td class="field"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Password:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="password" name="password" style="height:25px;width:155px;" onKeyPress='return alphanumericPass(event, false)' type="password" maxlength="12" placeholder="Password" /></td>
                <td class=""></td>
              </tr>          
              <tr>               
                <td class="field" align="left"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Email:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="email" name="email" style="height:25px;width:155px;" type="text" value="Email Address"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Email Address')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address'"/></td>
                <td class=""></td>
              </tr>     
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:200px;"><div><font size="1" color="#000000">By clicking 'Register Now' you are agreeing to our <a href="terms_con.php" target="_blank" style="color:red" > Terms and Conditions </a></font></div>  </td>
                </tr>   
            <tr align="">               
                <td class="field"  align="" colspan="2" style="padding-left:70px;">         
                <input align="left" value="" id="signupsubmit" name="signup"  type="image" src="images/nsignup.png" />                      
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

    </form>
```

Comment: Wait a second I just need to bring my crystal ball to see what error you are getting...

P.S. Provide at least some info about what is happening, what errors do you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma which shouldn't be there in the following code:

```
   password: {
        minlength: "password is 6 to 15 characters",
        maxlength:  "password is 6 to 12 characters 12",        
        required: " password should be required",       
    },
```

The comma at the end of this line needs removing: `required: " password should be required",`

Comment: Nearly all browsers are fine with having that extra comma.  And even if the validation script failed, it would still submit the form.

Comment: I didn't know that - thanks. Bad practice I guess, but still, good to know.

Comment: i am removed the ',' at the end of the password but not working the registration properley

Comment: No sorry, as pointed out by @Chris above, this won't be the reason. But I think this answer should remain because of Chris' insight?

Comment: HI i think email validation is not woking properly right.not displaying any error or correct message for email.@Alfie @chris

Comment: Are you sure the form is not submitting? Could it be an error in your php file: `email.php`? Are you tracking the page using something like FireBug to see what (if anything) is being sent and returned? Without more code, or seeing a live example, I don't think anyone can help you much more.

Comment: I have just realised, you have no `submit` element in your form. Try adding this before your `</form>` tag: `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: Pleased to hear it.. did my suggestion fix it, or did you find your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one you have no [submit input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html#input.submit). That might be the cause your [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) is not submitting, as some browsers fail to recognize the [image input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html).

If what you want is a submit button with a background image, I highly recommend you just style it in CSS and not use an input image.

Replace

```
<input align="left" value="" id="signupsubmit" name="signup"  type="image" src="images/nsignup.png" />
```

For this

```
<input type="submit" name="signup" id="signupsubmit" value="">
```

And in CSS, style it

```
#signupsubmit {
    background-image: url('images/nsignup.png');
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `type="image"` is equivalent to a submit button.

Comment: @str That is true. Technically, the HTML is indeed valid and the form _should_ submit. But historically [input image](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html)  has had problems in many browers, so what might be happening is that the browser he's using is not recognizing it or something.

Comment: I highly doubt that there is a visual browser that does not support `type="image"`. Do you know any?

Comment: @str If I recall correctly [Firefox 4 had some issues with it](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12687) (only being able to submit the form using the keyboard and not with the mouse press event or something along those lines).